# possible to use CURL to create exact replica of page?

Tags: php, curl

I'm working on a system for our users to position choose the location they want to put their adverts on pages of our website.

I want to create a preview of the host-page page inside a div on our Advert Positioning page (which i can then modify).

I've already investigated iframes (which works same-domain), but am interested to see whether CURL can perform the same task.

**Can CURL get a visually identical replica (code not image) of a page?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution Found:**

---

Works perfectly once you replace relative paths to stylesheets/imgs etc:

http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2007/06/php_tip_how_get_web_page_using_curl